# Pyspark: replace row value by another column with the same name

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe as below, df

```
| D1 | D2 | D3 |Out|
| 2  | 4  | 5  |D2 |
| 5  | 8  | 4  |D3 |
| 3  | 7  | 8  |D1 |
```

And I would like to replace the row values of the "out" column by the row value within the same row with the same column name of the row value of the "out" column.

```
| D1 | D2 | D3 |Out|Result|
| 2  | 4  | 5  |D2 |4     |
| 5  | 8  | 4  |D3 |4     |
| 3  | 7  | 8  |D1 |3     |
```

```
df_lag=df.rdd.map(lambda row: row + (row[row.Out],)).toDF(df.columns + ["Result"])
```

I have tried the code above and it could obtain the result but when I tried to save to csv, it keeps showing the error "Job aborted due to......" so I would like to ask if there is any other method could also obtain the same result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use chained `when` statements generated dynamically from the column names using `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Result', 
    reduce(
        lambda x, y: x.when(F.col('Out') == y, F.col(y)), 
        df.columns[:-1], 
        F
    )
)

df2.show()
+---+---+---+---+------+
| D1| D2| D3|Out|Result|
+---+---+---+---+------+
|  2|  4|  5| D2|     4|
|  5|  8|  4| D3|     4|
|  3|  7|  8| D1|     3|
+---+---+---+---+------+
```